# Dotted line, but every dot is a single CAShapeLayer?

Tags: ios, cashapelayer

I want to create a dotted line, like below

**..........................................**

But each dot must be a separate CAShapeLayer, as I want to set Stroke Color Alpha individually.

For instance, first dot has alpha 0.1, second has alpha 0.2, by this, when comes to middle, alpha would be 1.0, and as it will go on, it will again decrease.

Thanks.

NOTE: Don't give a single dotted line, I can make that, I want to apply every dot a respective opacity/alpha,

```
Lowest Alpha ----- Highest Alpha ----- Lowest Alpha
Starting Point ------Mid -------------End point
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi!. Take a look at CAReplicatorLayer. It should work if you want to reduce the same alpha value in each dot.

https://www.invasivecode.com/weblog/replicator-layers-lets-give-a-look-at-the/

You can combine it with animations, which is really cool ;)

Comment: Here is one Layer, which has dotted property, so I can't replicate it, I need to make one first, than replicate it.